# Bundle additional argument to Qt4 style QDBusConnection::connect() signal/slot connection

Tags: c++, qt, dbus, qdbus

I'm working with QtDbus and I need to handle DBus signal. I'm doing this by connecting DBus' signal to Qt slot like this:

```
bool res = QDBusConnection::systemBus().connect(kBusName, adapterPath, kInterfaceName,
        QLatin1String("PropertiesChanged"),
        this, SLOT(_handlePropertyChange(const QString &, PropertiesList , const QStringList &)));
```

Now, as there gonna be multiple DBus devices` signals handled in one Qt slot, I would like to send some additional information (device's address, which I have at the momment of connection) with this signal.

In Qt5-style connects, it's possible to do something like this with lambdas:

```
quint64 address;
bool res = QDBusConnection::systemBus().connect(kBusName, adapterPath, kInterfaceName,
        QLatin1String("PropertiesChanged"),
        this, [address, this](const QString & arg1, PropertiesList arg2, const QStringList &arg3) {
            _handlePropertyChange(const QString & arg1, PropertiesList arg2, const QStringList &arg3, address)
        }); //just an example of lambda connection, won't compile
```

But there are no Qt5-style connects availible for [QDBusConnection](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.5/qdbusconnection.html), and I understand this, as those connects are dynamic.

So question is: **how can I bundle additional argument to each QDBusConnection::connect()?**

Ideally, I would like to be able to do somethings like:

```
quint64 address;
bool res = QDBusConnection::systemBus().connect(kBusName, adapterPath, kInterfaceName,
        QLatin1String("PropertiesChanged"),
        this, SLOT(_handlePropertyChange(const QString &, PropertiesList , const QStringList &, quint64 adr = address /* bundle address here */)));
```